# Amazon signed me up for almost all Amazon Web Services. Is this usual?

Tags: amazon, registration, webservice

I wanted try Amazon SNS, so I clicked the Sign Up button on its tab on the management console. Amazon approved my signup and in my account under "Services You're Signed Up For" I see almost all Amazon's web services.

Is this normal?

Do they sign you up for everything in the hope you will use them?

They won't charge me for services I don't touch at all, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's strange, I recently added S3 to my account but didn't get all the other stuff lumped in.

AWS stuff is pay-as-you-go, so just having them activated in your account doesn't mean you're going to pay for them.

You can also remove 'activated' services from your account on that same page, if you just don't want them activated.

Comment: Yes, I can remove them one by one, but there's like 30, so it's a bit tedious. I hope you're right and it's completely "pay as you go" and there's no monthly fee just for having been signed up for a service. In that case it may be just a convenience that I'm signed up for all of them by default.

Comment: I've been signed up for AWS for a long time and haven't been charged for services I don't use, so you should be in the clear. If anything does happen you should contact [AWS Billing](http://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/), their customer service is great.